# How can I test catch block?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

How can I test catch block in below method in apex?

```
  @AuraEnabled
public static boolean updateHoldings(List<Holding__c> editedHoldingList){
    try{
        update editedHoldingList;

        return true;
    } catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're doing an `update` command, if you remove the `Id` value from any/all of the records in the `editedHoldingList`, that would get you into the catch block.

Something like:

```
Holding__c emptyHolding = new Holding__c(Name = 'Test123');
updateHoldings(new List<Holding__c>{emptyHolding});
```